# Spring WebFlux When populating Mono List<String> to a Map, map is always empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am new to Spring Web Flux. I read online that eventually, `WebClient` will be used over `RestTemplate`.

I am trying to populate the contents of a List that is returned by `WebClient` to a `Map`.
However, it is always blank or empty.

I saw some posts which talks about not using `block()` method. So, I use `subscribe()`

What is the correct way of doing this? I am certain that the endpoint should return a response because I tested it.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getShipment(List<String> orderNums) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> MAP_TYPE_REF = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
    };
    final String endpointUrl = "/the-path";
    final String queryParameter = "thequeryparam";

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String orderNo : orderNums) {
        Mono<List<String>> monoList = this.client.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(endpointUrl).queryParam(queryParameter, orderNo).build())
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(MAP_TYPE_REF);
        monoList.subscribe(list -> map.put(orderNo, list));
    }

    return map;
}
```

The method expects a list of order numbers `List<String> orderNums` where I need to loop through.

Response expected is

```
{
    "Items": {
        "123": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"]
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need to block or subscribe; you're constructing a data pipe; you can let your controller receive and forward a Mono or Flux.

The block() function explicitly locks the main thread until the publisher is finished. By the time it's finished, the call has been executed, resulting in the value being printed.

The subscribe() method, on the other hand, executes Mono asynchronously on a separate scheduler, leaving your main thread to finish. Because the default scheduler uses daemon threads to execute your subscription, your program will not wait for it to finish before terminating.

Because the WebClient request is non-blocking and returns a Mono that completes asynchronously, the map is empty. As a result, when the method returns the Map, the Mono may not yet be finished.

You can have something like this:

```
public Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> getShipment(List<String> orderNums) {
    final String endpointUrl = "/the-path";
    final String queryParameter = "thequeryparam";

    return Flux.fromIterable(orderNums)
            .flatMap(orderNo -> this.client.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(endpointUrl).queryParam(queryParameter, orderNo).build())
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
                    .map(items -> Map.of(orderNo, items)));
}
```

That is collected by a controller:

```
@RestController
public class ShipmentController {

    private final ShipmentService shipmentService;

    public ShipmentController(ShipmentService shipmentService) {
        this.shipmentService = shipmentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/shipments")
    public Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> getShipments(@RequestParam List<String> orderNums) {
        return this.shipmentService.getShipment(orderNums);
    }
}
```

The controller simply returns this Flux to the client, which subscribes to the stream and receives the maps as they become available.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved part of my problem.
By the way, just a little observation. Instead of 
`{
    "Items": {
        "123": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"]
    }
`}

I am getting

`{
    {
        "123": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"]
    },
 {
        "456": ["ITEM4", "ITEM5", "ITEM6"]
    },
`}

Comment: How do I format it with expected response shown in question details?